# Galois covers of curves of arbitrary degree.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, algebraic-curves, function-fields

For smooth projective algebraic curves over finite fields. Do they admit a finite Galois cover of any degree, that is not induced by just base extension?

Comment: What do you think of $\mathbb{P}^1$?

Comment: I think finite covers correspond to Galois extensions of $\mathbb{F}_q(t)$. So the question becomes whether this field has field extensions of all degrees that is not induced by just extending $\mathbb{F}_q$. I'm not sure how to classify all Galois extensions of this field, but one way is adding $n$-th root of $t$. Since the extension is supposed to be Galois, this implies adding all $n$-th roots of unity, which will lead to a finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_q$ and also adding $n$-th root of $t$. There might be problem when $n$ is a power of $p$ because it doesn't become separable.

Comment: Adjoining an $n$th root of $t$ gives a Galois extension of $\Bbb{F}_q(t)$ only when $n$ is a factor of $q-1$. For otherwise you are missing the required roots of unity. If $q=p^\ell$, $p$ a prime, that is not a problem at all. Look up Artin-Schreier extensions. Anyway, I don't know the answer. Not even in the case of $\Bbb{F}_q(t)$ (in other words, $\Bbb{P}^1$). IIRC the class field theory of function fields is developed well enough to give answers about Abelian covers. Unfortunately I'm not conversant with that, and don't know of a general recipe when constant field extensions are excluded.